# Stop batch file only processing last file?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have the following simple batch file for renaming *.txt files and removing the first x characters

```
@Echo Off

for %%i in ("*.txt") do (
  set fname=%%i
  echo %fname%
  copy %fname% %fname:~9%
)
```

However, it only processes the last file?  If I have 4 files in there, the last file gets copied 4 times as well?

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that %var% is replaced by the variable's value when the loop is first parsed, and doesn't change during execution.

Here's a demonstration which should allow you to fix your code:

```
@ECHO off&setlocal&CLS
ECHO Demonstrating the use of %%var%% IN a block
ECHO.
SET var=Original value
ECHO Before the block, %%var%%=%var%
FOR %%i IN (1 2 3) DO (
  SET var=New value %%i
  ECHO loop %%i : %%var%%=%var%
  )
ECHO After the block, %%var%%=%var%
ECHO.
ECHO BECAUSE the block is first PARSED, then executed.
ECHO in the parsing process, %%var%% is replaced by its
ECHO value as it stood when the block was parsed - BEFORE execution
ECHO.
ECHO now try using a SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION command first:
ECHO.
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET var=Original value
ECHO Before the block, %%var%%=%var% and ^^!var^^!=!var!
FOR %%i IN (1 2 3) DO (
  SET var=New value %%i
  ECHO loop %%i : %%var%%=%var% BUT ^^!var^^!=!var!
  )
ECHO After the block, %%var%%=%var% and ^^!var^^!=!var!
ECHO.
```

---

addendum

Oh, so many carets! An illiterate rabbit's paradise.

The caret character (`^`) "escapes" the special meaning of the character which follows - except for `%` which is escaped by another `%`
So - in the line

```
ECHO Before the block, %%var%%=%var%
```

What is echoed is "Before the block, " then a single `%` , the text `var`, another single `%`, `=` and `the value of var`

After `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` the character `!` becomes a special character. so

```
ECHO Before the block, %%var%%=%var% and ^^!var^^!=!var!
```

or

```
ECHO loop %%i : %%var%%=%var% BUT ^^!var^^!=!var!
```

appends a single `!`, the string `var`, another single `!` and `=` and `the run-time value of var` because at PARSE time, the `^^` is replaced by `^` and the resultant `^!` is then interpreted at EXECUTION time as a literal `!`. The `!var!` remains intact at PARSE time, but is replaced by the value of `var` at execution time.

Comment: Thank you!  Especially for teaching me rather than just fixing.  BTW: What do the carat's ^^^ do?  Is that the way to escape the '!'?

Comment: Did you mean `ECHO Before the block, %%var%%=%var% and ^^^!var^^^!=!var!`? Also a `pause` at the end?

Comment: +1, Nice explanation, I was about to put 'Try using delayed expansion' and then the code using delayed expansion when I saw your answer..

Comment: Seems to overdose on the carets - but what's happening is that a caret is used to `escape` the following character, that is, turn `OFF` its special meaning and treat it as a normal character. This works for all special characters - those that have a particular meaning to CMD - EXCEPT `%`, which is escaped by `%`. I'll add a little addendum to explain what actually happwns...

Comment: @user2033427 The addendum I've posted I hope explains why the caret-count is different inside a block from outside. That many carets outside a block would display carets.

Comment: @user2033427 The easy way to develop batch programs is to set up a shortcut to "Command Prompt" by Start>Programs>Accessories, right-click on "Command Prompt", send-to>Desktop from the context-menu. Then customise the short-cut. Right-click on the shortcut, select Propertis and set your 'Start in' directory to where you want to develop your programs.You can set other parameters to suit your preferences too. 
Once you've set up the shortcut, you don't need to pause to see the results of your batch as they will be maintained on a `CMD` window. Type `EXIT` to close the window when you're ready.

Comment: Why would the line `ECHO Before the block, ...` and the line `ECHO After the block, ...` be different? For some reason, when I save your code to a batch file and run it on my computer, only the triple caret version works for all three lines..

Comment: Because I stuffed it up. Good spotting. Corrected now.

Comment: This is a nice explanation, but you only need two carets to escape exclam.'s in delayed expansion: `echo ^^!` works.

Comment: @endoro Gee, I'm going to have to stop doing this during the wee hours of the morning. You're prefectly correct - and somehow, it seems to make more sense, too. Corrected (again) - although triple-^ worked, I'd say because the third caret escaped the `!`, which was simply unnecessary - like escaping a `B` or any other ordinary character...