# DOS Read, parse, then write to a file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have to need to read in a filename from each sub folder, find a string I am looking for, then write to a text file. The filename from each sub folder is always the same.

EDIT:  As for the data structure of the file...it is a XML files with TAGS in them.  I just want to search for these tags below, and write them to a text file.

Here's a snippet for the data (there are multiple track tags w/in the file:

```
             <track>
              <artists>
                <artist>
                    </read_only_info>
                    <primary>true</primary>
                    <language>en</language>
                    <artist_name>Kim Wilde</artist_name>
                    <roles>
                        <role>Primary</role>
                    </roles>
                </artist>
            </artists>
            <isrc>USMC18441630</isrc>
            </audio_file>
            <title>The Second Time</title>
            <locales/>
            <track_number>8</track_number>
         </track>
```

I use "find" to look for the string. This is what I have...

```
@ECHO OFF


SET filename=metadata.txt

FOR /F %%D in ('dir /b /a:D') DO (

(find /i "<artist_name>" "%%D\%filename%")
(find /i "<title>" "%%D\%filename%")
(find /i "<track_number>" "%%D\%filename%")

)
```

How do I assign variables for "artist_name", "title", and "track_number", then echo/print each variable to a file so that the result looks like

artist_name, title, track_number (comma delimited, for example)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your explanation is insuffizient. Have no clue about your data structure.

Comment: You must show much more of your xml, so that we can see TOKENS.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET filename=metadata.xml

(
FOR /F %%D in ('dir /b /a:D') DO IF EXIST "%%D\%filename%" (
CALL :process "%%D\%filename%"
)
)>result.txt
GOTO :eof

:process
CALL :filter %1 art  artist_name
CALL :filter %1 titl title
CALL :filter %1 trak track_number
ECHO "%art%","%titl%","%trak%"
GOTO :eof

:filter
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('type %1 ^|findstr /c:"<%3>"') DO (SET %2=%%i)
CALL SET "%2=%%%2:*%3=%%"
CALL SET "%2$=%%%2:*/%3=%%xx%3"
CALL SET "%2=%%%2:~1%%"
:lop
CALL SET "%2=%%%2:~0,-1%%"
CALL SET "%2$=%%%2$:~1%%"&IF DEFINED %2$ GOTO lop
GOTO :eof
```

COMPLETELY REPLACED code 20130423-0805Z

Caught in the delayed-expansion trap.

Running in my test system has over 300 subdirectories. Simplification and transfer didn't quite work...

This time for sure...

make sure file exists in subdirectory.

filter out from the file into (art titl trak) the contents between tags (artist_name title track_number)
display results

- results are redirected to the output file 'result.txt'

The `:FILTER` routine looks for the string supplied as the third argument ("tag") to `:FILTER`, within `<`..`>` and assigns the result to the variable given by the second `:filter` argument ("var")

- VAR is then assigned %var:*tag=% which strips everything up to the
  end of the tag string from VAR
- Next, VAR$ is assigned %var:*/tag%xxtag which is everything following
  the /tag (in case more data follows /tag) + the tag again + 2
  characters (xx=the / and <)
- The leading ">" is then removed from VAR
- A character is then lopped off of the end of VAR and VAR$ (which would be initialised to "anystraydataattheendoftheclosetagxxtag") until VAR$ is empty, which removes the close-tag and any extra data.

---

Ah- multiple track data per file.

the `>report.txt` simply sends the results to a file rather than the screen. Entirely optional

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET filename=%1&IF NOT DEFINED filename ECHO syntax:%~n0 startingdirname&GOTO :EOF 
PUSHD "%~1"
SET filename=metadata.xml

(
FOR /F %%D in ('dir /b /a:D') DO IF EXIST "%%D\%filename%" (
SET skipto=1
CALL :process "%%D\%filename%"
)
)>report.txt
POPD
GOTO :eof

:process
FOR %%i IN (art titl trak) DO SET "%%i="
CALL :filter %1 art  artist_name
IF NOT DEFINED art GOTO :eof
CALL :filter %1 titl title
CALL :filter %1 trak track_number
ECHO "%art%","%titl%","%trak%"
GOTO process

:filter
FOR /f "skip=%skipto% delims=" %%i IN (
  'type %1^|FINDSTR /n "$"') DO if not defined %2 (
  ECHO "%%i"|findstr /c:"<%3>" >nul
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   SET "%2=%%i"
   FOR /f "delims=:" %%L IN ("%%~i") DO SET skipto=%%L
   )
  )
)
IF NOT DEFINED %2 GOTO :EOF 
CALL SET "%2=%%%2:*%3=%%"
CALL SET "%2$=%%%2:*/%3=%%xx%3"
CALL SET "%2=%%%2:~1%%"
:lop
CALL SET "%2=%%%2:~0,-1%%"
CALL SET "%2$=%%%2$:~1%%"&IF DEFINED %2$ GOTO lop
GOTO :eof
```

Revised version.

processes each file found in `:process` after setting `skipto` to 1
 - clear variables to be used
 - try to find `ART` using the tag
 - if found, repeat with `titl` and `trak`, output and try again.
 - if not found, exit and go on to next file.

The `FILTER` procedure now 
 - looks at each line in the source, but numbers each line with `linenumber:` first. The first `%skipto%` lines are skipped.
 - finds the first line after the lines skipped which contains the target tag
 - sets the variable to the contents of the entire, numbered line and then grabs the portion of the numbered line up to, but not including the first colon and puts that into `SKIPTO`
 - other matching lines are ignored because the variable is now defined.

If the variable was not set in the routine, then there are no further data items after the `skipto` line, otherwise when we next look at the file, we know we've processed as far as the `skipto` line, so the next variable will be assigned to the next data item, skipping all previously-found items.

(edit 20130425-1640Z Added `PUSHD`/`POPD` to change to target relative root)

Comment: Peter, thanks for the quick response.  You are correct about the data.  It's  a text file with "tags" in them.
When I run this script, I see the following on the DOS prompt:

 "","",""

So this tells me it's not looking for the correct match.

I confirmed the "%%D\%filename%" value is correct, since it returns the patch+filename.

However, when I try to echo %tag%, I get nothing.

Comment: When to try to do "echo art is %art%" after the first FOR loop (before calling the show function, it does't return anything).

Comment: Nice collection of percenties :)

Comment: Your first response is puzzling. Given the examply you've posted, the response on my machine is "","The Second Time","8" and on correcting `tag=artistname` to `tag=artist_name` the results were "Kim Wilde","The Second Time","8" as expected. If you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012691/stop-batch-file-only-processing-last-file/16013139 I've posted a demo of why %art% in that position showed nothing. You could put that line safely in the `:show` routine

Comment: I had fixed the tag=artist_name.  The results are still the same... "","","".  I'm running this on a Win7-64 Pro SP1 if it makes any difference.  Not sure what I am doing wrong here...

Comment: adding "echo %art%" in the :show routine doesn't do anything (ie. same results).

Comment: Same results :(, even on a WinXP (virtual PC).  Note that when I do the following:

   @ECHO OFF

 
SET filename=metadata.xml


FOR /F %%D in ('dir /b /a:D') DO (
(find /i "<artist_name>" "%%D\%filename%")
(find /i "<title>" "%%D\%filename%")
(find /i "<track_number>" "%%D\%filename%")


I get results back:

---------- 00008811097226.ITMSP\METADATA.TXT
                <artist_name>Kim Wilde</artist_name>

---------- 00008811097226.ITMSP\METADATA.TXT
                <title>The Second Time</title>

---------- 00008811097226.ITMSP\METADATA.TXT
                <track_number>8</track_number>

Comment: Yup - totally my bad. Made untested changes in posting with tragic side-effects. Should work now...

Comment: Peter, great stuff.  We are getting closer.  It appears the script writes the output of the LAST iteration to result.txt.  There are multiple <track> tags w/in the file, and in each <track> tag, there's artist name, title, and track #.  I also note that the ECHO in the process routine does not display the output on the screen.  I'll try moving the ">result.txt" to different part and see if it does anything different.  Appreciate your help on this!

Comment: Writing the results to a text file is exactly what I want.  LOL..now with the revised version, it writes to report.txt, but the file has 0KB and it's empty :-)

Comment: Is the data reported to the screen when the `>report.txt` is removed?

Comment: Hi Peter, any other thoughts on this?  Thanks.

Comment: Ugh. Teach me to get a flu jab. Not been on top of my game for a little while. I suspect that you are not running from the directory from which your scan is to start. Just 3 extra lines - to check whether a parameter (starting directory name) has been supplied, and switch to it, then switch back. The `>report.txt` merely redirects the output to a file, so it can be removed if you like. If this version doesn't produce the expected results, it would be useful if you'd add `echo "%%D\%filename%"&` just before the `if exist` to show any filename that should be being scanned.

Comment: I like the >report.txt so I will keep it.  This way I can dump it into Excel and run a pivot.  Anyway, the script is in the same directory with all the sub-dirs that contain the metadata.xml file.  When I run the new updated script, I get "syntax:a startingdirname" at the command prompt.  The outputed text file still shows 0KB in size.  Feel better!

Comment: The syntax prompt is to show that you need to supply a directoryname as a parameter to your `a.bat` routine, so if your current directory is that subdirectory, `a .` will do. Or `a "whereveryourmetadata.xmlsare"` That way, `a.bat` can be anywhere on your path. Now if you'd add `echo "%%D\%filename%"&` just before the `if exist` to show any filename that should be being scanned. This would be the first debugging step - it works perfectly on my machine...

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong here, but I keep getting the same result, ie...it only gets the LAST values (name, title, track #) for the LAST tag....